# Асинхронный сервер на python

Tags: python

Как можно реализовать сервер на python который будет обрабатывать сразу несколько подключений? Желательно с примером.

Comment: Многопоточный сервер, а не асинхронный

Comment: [Пример решения на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520821/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На основе [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html)

- [HTTP клиент](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-http-client)
- [Echo-сервер](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-echo-server)

Дополнительно: [Writing a server with Python's asyncore module](http://parijatmishra.blogspot.com/2008/01/writing-server-with-pythons-asyncore.html).

А также [evserver](http://code.google.com/p/evserver/) - легковесный асинхронный Python WSGI сервер